# A specific reasoning for the use of frozenset here?

Tags: python

`from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta`

```
class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
  @abstractmethod
  def func(self):
    pass
  
  @abstractmethod
  def cnuf(self):
    pass
```

```
class B(A):
  pass
```

```
B.__dict__
```

```
mappingproxy({'__abstractmethods__': frozenset({'cnuf', 'func'}),
              '__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '_abc_impl': <_abc_data at 0x7f768d127720>})
```

As one would see in `__abstractmethods__`, we have a frozenset, what could be the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Probably as there's no need to to modify data set {'cnuf', 'func'}, the immutable set has been used.

Comment: Grepping the standard library of Python 3.10, I found no place where that value is used for hashing. Just making the value "read-only" imo does not warrant the usage of storing a frozen set. It could and probably should just be a regular `set`.